How to use DiscretePlot3D to plot 3D bars with white edges
The default color for the 3D Bar is Black, but I want to plot the 3D elements with a White border. How can i do it?
I have tried many different functions, but all of them have failed. I sincerely seek your guidance.
Thanks.

Crosstalk = {{0.01, 0.002137962, 0.016218101, 0.000870964, 
   0.005623413, 0.03801894, 1},
  {0.011220185, 0.020417379, 0.016595869, 0.001318257, 0.001479108, 1,
    0.005495409},
  {0.001348963, 0.000812831, 0.000446684, 0.000323594, 1, 0.001258925,
    0.000123027},
  {0.003090295, 0.003467369, 0.001513561, 1, 0.005128614, 0.001071519,
    0.000263027},
  {0.00020893, 0.000186209, 1, 0.000213796, 0.00042658, 0.00128825, 
   0.00616595},
  {0.007762471, 1, 0.011481536, 0.001174898, 0.003162278, 0.019054607,
    0.003715352},
  {1, 0.033113112, 0.004365158, 0.000776247, 0.00676083, 0.005754399, 
   0.002344229}
  }

colorSettings = {{0., CMYKColor[.508, .204, .045, .28]}, {0.2, 
   CMYKColor[.1, .4, 0, .28]}, {0.5, CMYKColor[.509, .4028, 0, .28]}}

DiscretePlot3D[Crosstalk[[Mass, Radius]], {Mass, 1, 7}, {Radius, 1, 7},
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[colorSettings, #3] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ExtentSize -> 0.2,
 ExtentElementFunction -> "PlaneFadingCube",
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8, White],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.618*0.3},
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {30, 20}},
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1}},
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black],
   Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black],
   Rotate[Style["Normalized Crosstalk", 12, Bold, Black], 3.14/2]}, 
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 0.25, 
    0.5, 0.75, 1}},
 TicksStyle -> {{12, Bold}, {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}},
 PlotLabel -> "Crosstalk between different Modes",
 ImageSize -> 700,
 ScalingFunctions -> "Linear",
 Boxed -> False, BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]] ]


Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please take the Site Tour. Resources: Introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.

A change to the PlotStyle should do it. I have chosen Red color so that I could demonstrate it.
DiscretePlot3D[Crosstalk[[Mass, Radius]]
 , {Mass, 1, 7}, {Radius, 1, 7}
 , ColorFunction -> (Blend[colorSettings, #3] &)
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> True
 , ExtentSize -> 0.2
 , ExtentElementFunction -> "PlaneFadingCube"
 , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8, White], EdgeForm[Red]]
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.618*0.3}
 , ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {30, 20}}
 , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {
   Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black]
   , Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black]
   , Rotate[Style["Normalized Crosstalk", 12, Bold, Black], 3.14/2]
   }
 , Ticks -> {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
   , {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
   , {0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}}
 , TicksStyle -> {
   {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}
   }
 , PlotLabel -> "Crosstalk between different Modes"
 , ImageSize -> 700
 , ScalingFunctions -> "Linear"
 , Boxed -> False
 , BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]
 ]




Thank you very very very much！！！ You are my god !! TvT

You can (optionally) upvote the answer and/or accept it by clicking on the tick mark next to it.
